# How to use Parallel.ForEach with image object?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, memorystream, parallel.foreach

Now my method is :

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        stream.Close();
        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return byteArray;
}
```

[after read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx). And i still confuse and can't find a way to use this.

So my question is how to use `Parallel.ForEach` or Parallel anything with my method.

my goal is to speed this method by using more cores of CPU to speed this up anything advice?

ps. I not serious if i can do the parallel with my method and that not speed up anything
I just want to try this and record the result Thank all your guy .

Comment: There's nothing that can be paralleled in this case. All the operations need to happen sequentially. `ParallelLoop`, just like a regular loop, is used when you have a set of objects (e.g. an array of objects) and you need to iterate through them. If you had an `Image[]` then you could use the `Parallel.ForEach` to speed things up. This, however, might block the UI if the image is large. In that case, you can put it on a different thread using a `Task` object.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use the parallel processing if you have multiple images.

Imagine going through seperate images in a for each loop you could do this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(images, img =>
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            stream.Close();
            byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The name 'Images' does not exist in the current context how to declare images what it suppose to be thank this is very interesting

Comment: As other peoples said: In the snippet you posted there is no chance to parallelize anything. In case you have mulitple images and do the same operation for each of them over and over again - THEN you can parallelize things. Parallel.For / ForEach only helps if you are repeating operations on items of collections. Otherwise they are useless. You could however let the saving of the image happen in a task. Go look for the "Task Parallel Library" on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to speed up the code you could do :

```
            BitmapData d = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            int length = Math.Abs(d.Stride) * image.Height;
            byte[] buff = new byte[length]; 
            Marshal.Copy(d.Scan0, buff, 0, length);
            image.UnlockBits(d);

            return buff;
```